# (Blender 2.8) Control + RMB doesn't create new vertex

Tags: modeling, vertices, shortcut

First off, I want to tell that I'm a complete beginner to Blender.

I'm following a modelling tutorial on YouTube. Not only is the interface different, but the shortcuts are too. The person making the tutorial tells you to create a new vertix with Ctrl + LMB. However this has changed in Blender 2.8. Websites tell me to use Ctrl + RMB instead. But nothing happens when I press Ctrl + RMB. All help is appreciated. (I do not like people telling me that I'm stupid or stuff like that, since that doesn't help me.)

Thanks in advance,
Nofontnl

Comment: Please check that you're in edit mode, have vertex select enabled and not vertices selected (Alt + A). Then you should be able to use Ctrl + RMB for adding a single, new and disconnected vertex.

Comment: How do I know if I have vertex select enabled? (I am in edit mode, I'm able to see that in the workflow tab.) I tried pressing Alt + A, but nothing really happens. 
When I hold Ctrl + RMB it selects the same way the lasso tool does in paint.net.

Comment: The icons for this are next to the edit mode dropdown and look like [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting.html#select-mode-header-buttons) (Screenshot in the manual is from an older version of Blender so it looks a bit different).

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to delete the other vertice, faces and edges of the cube and only keep my own vertice and stuff?

Comment: Sure, you can delete any part of the mesh by selecting it, pressing X and choosing what part of the selection you'd like to delete (*Mesh > Delete* when you're using the menus).